# when using matplotlib, AttributeError: 'numpy.datetime64' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

Tags: python

I just plot the sp500 data using matplotlib, and I got an error of

> AttributeError: 'numpy.datetime64' object has no attribute
> 'toordinal'.

I googled for a long time and I didn't find a solution. Can somebody help me? thanks

```
    plt.plot(SP500_df['Date'], 
         SP500_df['Adj Close'], label=SYMBOL, color='green')
```

I did print(SP500_df.info()) and it does show the date column is a type of datetime64.

```
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------     --------------  -----
 0   Date       83 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 1   Adj Close  83 non-null     float64
```

I am using python 3.6 and before showing the above error, there was a warning  of

C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py:248: FutureWarning: Support for multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. `obj[:, None]`) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.  Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead

I googled for a long time and I didn't find a solution. Can somebody help me? thanks

Comment: Toordinal is the class method for date object. It seems that your SP500_df object is calling the toordinal function somewhere. np.datetime datatype doesn't have the toordnal attribute. If you're calling the function somewhere, I would change the data format to an np.datetime readable attribute. More can be found here - https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html

Comment: Thanks, if I run the script using spyder, it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I solved the problem by two solutions:

solution 1: using .values, for example

```
    plt.plot(SP500_df['Date'].values, 
         SP500_df['Adj Close'].values, label=SYMBOL, color='green')
```

But I still don't understand why?

Solution 2: upgrade matplotlib and keep everything the same

Thanks